# Workflow: Animation project to Web Background. Is WebGL/HTML5/ Javascript a viable alternative to video background limitations. Advice needed.

Tags: javascript, python, html, three.js, cinema-4d

As many before me, I now face the greatest challenge any web dev/designer must encounter: creating a personal portfolio. If you're a perfectionist like me, then you know how difficult it is to find satisfaction in any one idea, especially when that idea is meant as a direct reflection upon your talent, skills, and overall ability. Making a website for a client: No problem. Making a website for yourself: Battle of the Century.

My previous personal portfolio websites were always basic, in that they used many of the common elements one might find in a typical web portfolio. A little jQuery Isotopes here, a little Scroll.js there, wrap it up behind Foundations framework for responsive design. Boom. Instopresto, you've got a portfolio...one that looks and feels like everyone elses.

Now I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel. A portfolio should accomplish what it is meant to do, display ones previous experience/work and encapsulate ones overall "ability" or skill level.

For this round I really wanted to go with a full width video background. The other design elements are easy to pull off. Give the site an offset menu, perhaps go with a onepage minimalistic design, or use Ajax for page/content navigation.

I keep having trouble with the video background. It's the limitations we face with HTML5 video and how it displays on mobile device. Forcing or tricking a user into having to press a play button is one extra step that kills the idea, and using an image as a fallback defeats the awesomeness of using a video in the first place.

There is an alternative though. Using Three.js and taking advantage of the technology offered in machines today via graphics rendering, let's create an animation for use as a full width background. It's cross browser compatible and works well on tablets and mobile devices.

My question is to those with heavy Javascript or python experience and those who have utilized three.js before. I typically use Cinema4D for animation as it provides a fluid and seamless workflow between itself and After Effects. I've already created a 3D element, given it animation, and created a camera to capture it all.

How can one export from Cinema4D for WebGL use and Three.js. Most tutorials/information on the web is extremely outdated. Even a viable workflow from C4D to Blender to WebGL would work for me if only someone who understands the process could explain it.

Here are a few examples that have fueled the inspiration behind this project:

http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/threejs/css3d/periodictable/ - Built using CSS3 for the overall functinality, this is AWESOME and really what I am going for in replicating aesthically.

http://blogs.truthlabs.com/2013/11/12/illustrator-webgl-workflow-tips/ - This tutorial is fantastic, but being based out of Blender I am in no mans land. For a simple solution, this works fine. Creating in C4D would take no time at all, its how to get it to WebGL.

Thank you for any advice and taking the time to read through this post.

-Cheers,
Branden Dane

Comment: Seeing as I don't have 10 rep points, here are other great links for reference: http://vimeo.com/50094587 - Great, high functionable site built and design in C4D http://www.ro.me/ - If you haven't seen this site/are really bored with even having read this post, CHECK THIS OUT. If anything, seeing this is worth dealing with my rambling. http://helloracer.com/webgl/ - Beutifully designed. Minimal, yet effective.

http://www.playmapscube.com/ - It's Google, it's gonna look awesome duh.

Comment: Are you asking how to render a video sequence using WebGL or how to port your c4d scene into a realtime engine?

Comment: Ideally, port a c4d file to work with Three.js. As I understand it, Blender is the only animation software which plays nicely with Javascript on export. Alternatively, a workflow solution from c4d to Blender to Javascript. The final goal being to create an interactive interface/background for a website. It's been done before, especially by Google labs peeps. Thank you.

Comment: I think you will still have to learn three.js. I'm not entirely sure what makes blender better, but i can imagine the open source nature having to do something with it. People have written exporters for other software, but, regardless of that, people have also written importers for three.js which take industry standard files. You might be able to export some animation, but i think you will still have to dive into three.js. c4d and three are two completely different things. Look into glTF for example.

Comment: @pailhead I definitely agree with your statement. I apologize for not making it clear. While I am not the greatest with three.js, I understand it dynamics, as well as how to manipulate its core code base and various add-ons.If an importer works that you know of from C4D to Three.js I am all ears my friend.

Comment: Not sure :( i just looked at opencollada but its for max and maya.

Comment: Is there no collada/dae exporter for C4D? I think you should also consider that both video and a 3D scene take up quite a lot of bandwidth and you should think about if you want to present your portfolio with a 1 minute loading screen for proper video resolution/high detailed background 3D scene.

Comment: I'd use video if it weren't for the native restrictions within Apple to keep from allowing html5 video to autoplay. It adds an extra level to the overall UX I don't agree with. And having an image as a fallback defeats the whole point of having an awesome video in the first place. I've played alot with three.js and the CSS3D renderer. CRAZY potential here. @pailhead yea it seems that Max and Maya get all the love for export. Dunno why. The new seamless integration between After Effects and Cinema4D would make me think so many more users trying C4D.

Comment: And thank you for your thoughts on this guys. WebGL isn't new but I think it's potential has yet to even begin to be discovered. Video games are obvious, but interaction for websites on a whole new level. It's cool stuff.